# Boost Static Assertion for Type Comparision

Tags: c++, cuda, assertion

The following problem gives me compiler errors and I am not sure how to write it correctly

```
struct FalseType { enum { value = false }; };
struct TrueType { enum { value = true }; };


template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsSame
{
typedef typename FalseType Result;
};


template <typename T>
struct IsSame<T,T>
{
typedef typename TrueType Result;
};

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( (IsSame< Foo::FooClass1 , Foo::FooClass1 >::Result::value) );
```

This static assertion should not fail when used, but somehow the compiler NVCC from CUDA gives me the following error:

```
error C2338: (IsSame< Foo::FooClass1 , Foo::FooClass1 >::Result::value)
```

I dont know what to do, all other STATIC ASSERTIONS work but the type comparision does not , what is wrong up there? Typo? Brackets?

I cant get my type comparision to work under NVCC?

Any ideas?

IT SEEMS THAT MSVC (which is routed to by NVCC) has its problems as well with the above version.... hm...

============= EDIT ========================
HERE A SNIPPET WHICH DOES NOT WORK IN MSVC!

This snipped should compile in MSVC, but it does not, so I assume compiler bug:

error C2118: negative subscript ( WHHHHHYYYYYY) strange....

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


struct FalseType { static const bool  value = false ; };
struct TrueType {  static const bool  value = true ; };


template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsSame
{
  typedef ::FalseType Result;
  static const bool result = false;
};


template <typename T>
struct IsSame<T,T>
{
typedef ::TrueType Result;
static const bool result = true;
};

namespace OtherType{
   struct Type1{};
};

template< typename _T> // Settings from below
struct Settings{
   typedef _T myT;
   typedef char static_assert_failed[ ((IsSame< _T,OtherType::Type1>::Result::value)) ? 1 : -1 ]; // USE HERE only ::result works, (BUT WHY)
};

int main(){

   cout << (IsSame<OtherType::Type1,OtherType::Type1>::Result::value)<< endl;

}
```

Comment: Not sure about NVCC and your error, but you could simplify the construction a lot by saying `template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsSame : FalseType {};` and `template <typename T> struct IsSame<T,T> : TrueType {};`.

Comment: Does the same code work under GCC?  If so, it's probably a but in NVCC.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef typename FalseType Result;
typedef typename  TrueType Result;
```

This is wrong, because `FalseType` and `TrueType` aren't dependent names and therefore `typename` is illegal here.

It should be

```
typedef FalseType Result;
typedef  TrueType Result;
```

***Update***

It seems that

```
IsSame < _T, OtherType::Type1 >::Result::value
```

is illegal. The thing is that

```
IsSame < _T, OtherType::Type1 >::Result
```

must be qualified by `typename` but syntactically it is impossible, that is, the following is illegal, too

```
(typename IsSame <_T, OtherType::Type1 >::Result)::value
```

I found the following solution which makes it work.

```
typedef typename IsSame <_T, OtherType::Type1 >::Result RealResult;
typedef char static_assert_failed[RealResult::value ? 1 : -1];
```

HTH.

Comment: It's legal to use typename on a non-dependent name (in the right context), but it's illegal here because it's being applied to an unqualified name. (14.6/5)

Comment: this is not the reason why it does not work, MSVC does something wrong... ehm look above with the snippet, but thanks for that to mention it! It was wrong :-)

Comment: @Gabriel: Hm.... This is very interesting. I am looking at it now. Will update if I find anything

Comment: Ahh ok, jeah :-) thanks for that to point out, I did not see that! SO i Need a better IsSame comparision...

Comment: @Gabriel: Check out this question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642721/multiple-nested-dependent-names-where-to-stick-the-typename-keyword