# multiple nested dependent names - where to stick the typename keyword?

Tags: c++, templates, typename, dependent-name

This question was inspired by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642050/boost-static-assertion-for-type-comparision). While trying to answer that question, I understood that I have a lot of questions myself. So... Consider the following:

```
struct S1
{
    enum { value = 42 };
};

template <class T> struct S2
{
    typedef S1 Type;
};

template <class T> struct S3
{
    typedef S2<T> Type; 
};

template <class T> struct S4
{
    typedef typename T::Type::Type Type;  //(1)//legal?
    enum {value = T::Type::Type::value }; //(2)//legal?
};

int main()
{
    S4<S3<S2<S2<S1> > > >::value;
}
```

This compiles successfully with MSVC9.0 and Online Comeau. However, ***what's bothering me is that I don't understand what `typename` refers to in (1) and why wouldn't we need `typename` in (2).***

I have tried these 2 syntaxes (syntaces?) of what I think it should be both of which fail on MSVC:

```
    typedef typename T::typename Type::Type Type;
    enum {value = typename T::typename Type::Type::value };
```

and

```
    typedef typename (typename T::Type)::Type Type;
    enum {value = (typename (typename T::Type)::Type)::value };
```

Of course, a workaround is to use consecutive `typedef`s like this:

```
   typedef typename T::Type T1;
   typedef typename T1::Type Type;
   enum { value = Type::value};
```

Good style left aside, do we syntactically ***have to*** use the workaround I mentioned?

***The rest is just an interesting example. No need to read. Not that relevant to the question.***

Please note, that although MSVC accepts the original strange syntax without multiple `typename`s(I mean (1) and (2)), it leads to strange behavior as in the mentioned question. I think I'll present that example in concise form here as well:

```
struct Good
{
    enum {value = 1}; 
};
struct Bad
{
    enum {value = -1};  
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct ArraySize
{
    typedef Bad Type;
};
template <class T>
struct ArraySize<T, T>
{
    typedef Good Type;
};

template <class T>
struct Boom
{
    char arr[ArraySize<T, Good>::Type::value]; //error, negative subscript, even without any instantiation
};

int main()
{
    Boom<Good> b; //with or without this line, compilation fails.
}
```

This doesn't compile. The workaround I mentioned solves the problem, but I am sure the problem here is my initial question - missing typename, but you don't really know where to stick one.
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: The example is indeed interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name before the scope operator `::` must always be a namespace or class (or enumeration) name, and namespace names can't be dependent.  So you don't have to tell the compiler that this is a class name.

---

I'm not just making this up, the standard says (section `[temp.res]`):

> A qualified name used as the name in a mem-initializer-id, a base-specifier, or an elaborated-type-specifier is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. In a *nested-name-specifier* that immediately contains a *nested-name-specifier* that depends on a template parameter, the identifier or simple-template-id is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the `typename` keyword. [ Note:
>   The `typename` keyword is not permitted by the syntax of these constructs.  — end note ]

`T::`, `T::Type::`, and `T::Type::Type::` are *nested-name-specifiers*, they do not need to be marked with `typename`.

This section clearly could have, and arguably should have, included the *type-specifier* of a typedef declaration in the list of exemptions.  But remember that *type-specifiers* can get really complicated, especially in typedef declarations.  Right now it's quite possible to need the `typename` keyword multiple times in a typedef *type-specifier*, so a lot more analysis would be needed to convince me that `typename` is never necessary in a typedef.

In `typedef typename T::Type::Type Type`, `T::Type::Type` requires use of the `typename` keyword, because its *nested-name-specifier* (`T::Type::`) is a dependent name, and the standard says (same section):

> When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be preﬁxed by the keyword typename, forming a typename-specifier.  If the qualified-id in a typename-specifier does not denote a type, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: With the same logic I could say that after `typedef` only a type is expected so we wouldn't have to ever tell the compiler `typedef typename ...` So no, I'm not buying it :)

Comment: I don't seem to find any confirmation of what you're saying. Could you please name chapter and verse?

Comment: @Armen the quoted text was not part of C++03. But that was an accident. It was added as a result of a FCD comment about pointer to member declarators (`T Dependent::MyClass::*`) not allowing `typename`. The committee noticed the bigger picture problem and added the bugfix to all cases of nested name specifiers embedded into a qualified-id. (see http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/c++0x-now-at-fcd.html at "19:00:31 on Saturday, 22 May 2010").

Comment: Note that C++20 will allow `typename` to be omitted in many (but not all) places, including `typedef` (or any other declarator-based declaration) at namespace or class scope.

Answer (score 3):

The point of typename is to allow basic checking of a template definition before it is instantiated. Parsing C++ is impossible without knowing whether a name is a type or not (is `a*b;` an expression statement or a declaration of a pointee `b`).

In a template definition the category (type or non-type) of a simple identifier is always known. But a qualified (dependent) name cannot be - for arbitrary T, T::x could be either.

So the language allows you to tell the compiler that a qualified name represents a type by using the typename keyword. If you don't, the compiler is required to assume it to be a value type. In either case it is an error to mislead the compiler.

The rule applies even in some cases where it is obvious a type is required (eg in a typedef).

Only the full qualified name requires this disambiguation - `typename A::B::C` tells you C is a type; there's no need to know anything about A or B to parse the context in which the qualified name appears.

In your example (1) the typename is saying that `T::Type::Type` is a type. In (2) you must not use typename, because `T::Type::value` is not a type. Neither case says anything about `T::Type` because this is irrelevant. (Although one can deduce that it must be a type, because otherwise you couldn't apply `::` to it.)

I suspect your problem with MSVC is simply a bug in that compiler (it's notorious that it doesn't handle two-phase lookup properly), although I have to admit I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: +1 for a thorough explanation. I still hope to see some Standard quote in one of the answer but it doesn't seem anybody had one handy.

Comment: So, what from 14.6 can you quote that back up your claim?

Comment: @VJo All of it! 14.6/3 and 14.6/5 make it clear that typename only affects a _qualified-id_. If you look at the grammar, `A::B::C` is a _qualified-id_ but the prefix `A::B` is not, so typename cannot affect it. (A _qualified-id_ is, loosely, a _nested-name-specifier_, a series of class/namespace names each followed by ::, followed by an _unqualified-id_.)

Comment: The prefix `A::B` is a qualified-id in the Standard too. The Standard calls any qualified name a *qualified-id* (which is a bit confusing, but is convenient). It does not depend on the parser tree of the nested-name-specifier (in which the non-terminal `qualified-id` does not appear). They are explicitly defined to be qualified-ids. For example "A nested-name-specifier that denotes a class, optionally followed by the keyword template (14.2), and then followed by the name of a member of either that class (9.2) or one of its base classes (Clause 10), is a qualified-id".

Comment: You can apply that quote to `A::B::`, if `A` is a class. Because `A::` is a nested-name-sepecifier followed by the name of a member of it. If you look around in the spec, it uses that row of definitions of "qualified-id" given by clause 5.1 everywhere.

Comment: @Johannes: I disagree. Eg 3.4.3.1/1 makes it clear that a qualified-id is one nested-name-specifier followed by a simple name. There's no way to parse A::B::C in a way which makes A::B a qualified-id, because a qualified-id cannot be followed by ::. Also, 9.2/1 makes clear that a nested class B is not a _member_ of surrounding class A, it is a nested type within it. So A::B is *not* a nested-name-specifier followed by the name of a member and 5.1/7 does not apply. (Nor should it, since it is talking about primary-expressions; A::B is not an expression if B is a class.)

Comment: @Alan you cannot make sense of the spec if you take that point of view (the rules are set such that you are forced to take my point of view in order to make sense of it, or I missed something very bad all the time, which I think is very unlikely). Also, you are wrong about the nested class B not being a member of the nesting class. It indeed is a member.

Comment: @Johannes: Hmm, 9.2/1 doesn't actually say that. However, I still don't think 5.1/7 is intended to override the grammar. It's only talking about expressions, and I don't believe "member" there is intended to cover nested types.

Comment: @Johannes: Can you show me somewhere where A::B in A::B::C is regarded as a qualified-id?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1361/discussion-between-alan-stokes-and-johannes-schaub-litb)

Comment: @Alan I'm going to point you to a few places where the non-terminal "qualified-id" does not appear, but still is used to refer to the respective qualified name (it's easy to find more): 3.4.3.1p1, 3.4.3.2p1, 14.6p3 ("If the qualified-id in the typename-specifier ..."), 14.6.2.1p4bullet2, 14.6.2.1p6, 14.1p2 (typename A::B, where A::B will be a nested-name-specifier identifier grammatically. Grammatically, there is no qualified-id).

Comment: @Johannes I concede that the standard (ab)uses qualified-id in situations where the grammar contains "nested-name-specifier some-simple-id" rather than specifically the qualified-id non-terminal. But that doesn't mean that A::B in A::B::C is a qualified-id even in that extended sense. A::B::C is A::B:: followed by an identifier, which fits the pattern, but A::  followed by B::C does not.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef typename T::Type::Type Type;  //(1)//legal?
enum {value = T::Type::Type::value }; //(2)//legal?
```

in (1) you say that T::Type::**Type** is a type name

in (2) you say nothing about T::Type::Type::**value** and by default it will be parsed as non-type

Answer (score -1):

> typedef typename T::Type::Type Type; 
>   //(1)//legal?

I myself **don't understand** the need of `typename` here. Becuase `typedef` can be applied only to a `typename`. Maybe C++ grammer is designed this way.

> enum {value = T::Type::Type::value };
>   //(2)//legal?

You **cannot** use `typename` because, it's expected to be a value. It's implicitly logical, that when you write `enum { value = ??? };`, then `???` must always be a value only.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I ***do*** understand why we need typename in (1), I just don't understand why only 1. I think we need more. The same applies to (2). I know that value is a value, but `Type::Type` must be qualified with `typename` before we can extract its `value`

Comment: @Armen, When we are scoping towards `value` using `::` (i.e. `T::Type::Type::value`), how can one use `typename`. It would have been a very unusal syntax, if it was there.

Comment: I need typename because both `T::Type` and `T::Type::Type` are dependent names

Answer (score -4):

The `typename` refers to the first dependent type. In your particular case :

```
typedef typename T::type1::type2 Type;
```

it refers to `T::type1`, telling it is a dependent name (depending on the template parameter T).

For a constant value, you do not need a typename, because it is a value - not a type. If the value is not defined, you'll get a compilation error.

**EDIT**

```
struct S1
{
    enum { value = 42 };
};
template <class T> struct S2
{
    typedef S1 Type;
};
template <class T> struct S3
{
    typedef S2<T> Type; 
};
template <class T> struct S4
{
    typedef typename T::Type::Type Type;  //(1)//legal?
    enum {value = T::Type::Type::value }; //(2)//legal?
};
```

Lets go slowly through the example. What happens in this `S4<S3<S2<S2<S1> > > >` type is this : since T is `S3<S2<S2<S1> > >`, then `typename T::Type` expands to `S2<S2<S1> >::Type`, which is a full type (not depending in any way on the template parameter any further). For that reason you do not need to use typename after the first dependent typename.

Comment: In this case, I definitely need a typename in context like this: `typename T::Type1::value1` if typename refers to Type1, right? And second, How do I tell the compiler that `Type2` is also a typename in `T::Type1::Type2`

Comment: @Armen Well, you tell that `Type2` is a type, exactly like you did. It doesn't depend on the template parameter, but it should be defined within the `Type1` somehow.

Comment: I don't think you're right. If the compiler needs to be told that `T::Type1` is a type, then it also should be told that `T::Type1::Type2` is a type (not an enumerator, for example)

Comment: @Armen Regarding the constant, if you use `typename` it should just be ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @Armen But you are telling that `Type2` should be a type defined within `Type1`, which is declared within the template argument T. If you pass an enum, the compilation will fail at the moment of the template instantiation.

Comment: It's not that simple. If what you describe were the case we wouldn't need the typename keyword at all. Ever heard of two-phase name lookup?

Comment: @VJo @Armen I'm convinced `typename T::Type1::Type2` is declaring that Type2 is a type, not Type1. See 14.6 in the standard.